# Merge an unknown field of end-group tag, indicating that the corresponding start-group was missing

Tags: c#, networking, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I'm trying to parse RPC-Header from ssl-stream:

```
private SslStream stream;
var rpcHeader = Header.Parser.ParseInt16DelimitedFrom(stream);
```

Parse function:

```
internal static T ParseInt16DelimitedFrom<T>(this MessageParser<T> parser, Stream input) where T : IMessage<T> {
  ProtoPreconditions.CheckNotNull(input, "input");
  var size = (input.ReadByte() << 8) + input.ReadByte();
  var buffer = new byte[size];
  input.Read(buffer, 0, size);
  return parser.ParseFrom(buffer);
}
```

Error:

```
 Merge an unknown field of end-group tag, indicating that the corresponding start-group was missing.    at Google.Protobuf.UnknownFieldSet.MergeFieldFrom(UnknownFieldSet unknownFields, ParseContext& ctx)
```

I understand very little about how Protobuf works, and I'm having trouble finding an answer to the error in the official documentation, what does it mean, and in what direction should I move?

Thanks.